# How to trace a process to original user?

Tags: process, users, solaris, su

Say, on a Solaris server, `user1` logs in, switches to someother user, say `sruser`, using `su -` and then starts a process of id `X`. And then another user `user2` logs in, switches to `sruser` the same way and starts a process of id `Y`. (Multiple users can log in and swithch to `sruser` simultaneously.)

In the above scenario, is there any way we can trace the processes of ids `X` and `Y` to the actual users `user1` and `user2`?

How can we trace a process to the original user?

Answer (score 1):

there are commands to generate the process tree. The  'ps' take options 'fu' , and i think sun has ptree.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards ptree. It did give encouraging results. From the process tree, with a little guess work, i was able to trace back to the actual user. But i'm not sure what this process is - `/usr/lib/ssh/sshd`. I've heard of `ssh` but not `sshd`.

Comment: sshd will be ssh deamon .. sth that talks to to ssh, which is on client site ..  just like you have a http server ...

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way, and as far as I know there is no Solaris way either. If there was a reliable way to find out the “ancestor” user, the usual unix security model where root can do everything would not hold.

You can check each process's parent recursively. (Warning, untested script.)

```
pid=$1 pids=$pid user=
while pid=$(ps -o ppid= $pid); do
  user=$(ps -o ruser= $pid)
  case $user in
    0|root) :;;
    *) break;;
  esac
done
echo $user
```

This is not guaranteed to give any result, though. Maybe the parent's parent's parent process has exited.

You can check on what terminal a process is running (`ps -o tty= $pid`) and check who last logged in on that terminal (`who`, `last`). This is only indicative, though: root can start processes on any terminal.

What do you expect to see if user1 runs `su user2 -c 'su user1 -c …'`? It's conceivable that the OS would track the successive authentication chains in the kernel data structures associated with the process, but that's very far from the usual unix security model.